# Exporting Query Results to Tab-Delimited CSV in DBeaver

Tags: sql, csv, export, dbeaver

I am trying to export the results of a SQL query to a CSV file with a tab delimiter using DBeaver. However, I'm facing issues in getting the output in the desired format. Here's what I have tried:

1. Executed the SQL query in DBeaver's SQL editor.
2. Right-clicked on the result set and selected "Export Resultset".
3. Chose CSV as the export format and set the delimiter to `\t` for tab-delimited output.
4. Selected the destination for the output file and completed the export process.

Despite these steps, the resulting CSV file does not seem to be correctly tab-delimited. I am not sure if I am missing a setting or if there is a specific way to input the tab delimiter in DBeaver.

Has anyone encountered this issue or knows the correct procedure to export a query result to a tab-delimited CSV file in DBeaver? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just checked the issue in my DBeaver, everything is ok. The \t delimiter should be set here. May be you need to update DBeaver?
[image]

Comment: You are right. That works. I just updated DBeaver to 23.3.0.